# Place words in a given font in index entries in a document at location of marked words

Tags: vba, ms-word

Goodevening everybody,

I made a VBA code which loops through all the words in a document and checks if the used font of that word is *SimSun*. If the font is SimSun, the word should be marked for the overall index. So I made this code:

```
Sub toevoegen()

Dim doc As Document

Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each sentence In doc.StoryRanges
    For Each w In sentence.Words
        If w.Font.Name = "SimSun" Then
            doc.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=Selection.Range, Entry:=w
        End If       
    Next   
Next
    
End Sub
```

The code works, but there is one problem. The index entries are placed at the end of the document. I want them to be placed after the words which where marked. So this is the result when you run the code:

[image: the problem: The indexes are at the end]

And I want it to be after the word *SimSun* and *Previous*. I am stuck. Can somebody help me?

Comment: "StoryRanges" represent "streams" of material in a word document, such as "the main body but not text in shapes", various header/footer "streams", and "text in shapes" (e.g. in textboxes. I would guess most people only index text in the main body, and although { XE } fields are allowed in headers/footers, I don't think the { INDEX } field picks them up. But do you actually need to index "text in shapes" - if so, AFAIK it has to be done rather differently from the main body text.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. I don't know if I understand you correct but you mean that the code works only in the 'main body' of the document? And not headers or footers?

Comment: 1. You can insert { XE } fields in headers/footers (they don't cause an error). But they don't result in Index entries created by the { INDEX } field. So probably better not to create those { XE } fields. 2. As it stands, macropod's code processes the main body. If that's all you need, it should be fine.

Comment: 3. If you have text boxes or other text in shapes with words marked with SimSun font, I think looping through *all* the StoryRanges will fail because .MarkEntry does not work in that Story Typ, and FInd/Replace in that story type also does not work the same way so I don't think you can use macropod's code as it stands to do it. But you can create { XE } entries in that story type and { INDEX } does pick them up. There are other story types I haven't investigated at all such as Footnotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Find/Replace is likely to be far quicker than looping through every 'sentence':

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, StrIdx As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Font.Name = "SimSun"
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    StrIdx = .Text
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.Add .Duplicate, wdFieldEmpty, "XE " & StrIdx, False
    .MoveEndUntil Chr(21), wdForward
    .End = .End + 1
    .Font.Reset
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      If .End = .Cells(1).Range.End - 1 Then
        .End = .Cells(1).Range.End
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        If .Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker) = True Then
          .End = .End + 1
        End If
      End If
    End If
    If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a whole other way to look at it. I looked at your code and was wondering why you choose to make an own code for tables? When I strip your code it does work fine. In the second `with` I only need the `.Font.Name="SimSun"` right? Why do we need the other lines?

Comment: Additional code is required for tables - and the end of the document - in case the SimSun font has been applied to the end-of-cell and/or end-of row markers or the last paragraph mark in the document. If those don't conditions ever apply, the corresponding code can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

### It is putting the index entry at your selection point.

You can move the selection point.

Try:

```
Sub toevoegen()
  Dim doc As Document
  Set doc = ActiveDocument
  For Each sentence In doc.StoryRanges
    For Each w In sentence.Words
        If w.Font.Name = "SimSun" Then
            w.Select
            Selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
            doc.Indexes.MarkEntry Range:=Selection.Range, Entry:=w
        End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

That will insert the index entry just after the target word. Running it multiple times will result in multiple entries for each word.

Comment: I am more familiar with VBA in Excel so I don't know the Word library that well, but the basic is the same right? In Excel I try to avoid selections because selecting the word costs time and memory right? Your code does exactly what I want by the way! Thanks for your help.

Comment: The selection object is not great in Word, either. However, your macro was placing the entry at the selection point. If this is a long document, you can turn screen updating off before running the procedure. Take a look at macropod's response as well.